# EBNF for math equations and inequalities

Tags: compiler-construction, syntax, latex, parsing

I would like to design a math language satisfying EBNF, to let me write equation systems and inequalities as close to natural math language as possible. I would like to have two parsers for this little language, one parser prepares the equalities/inequalities written in this language for publication, another parser prepares it for computing, i.e., retrieve all coefficients into memory and store them in my own data structure for further computing. I was thinking to use Latex2e syntax, so I don't need to write the first parser for publication. However I read from this forum that Latex2e syntax itself doesn't contain enough information for a parser. Any suggestions about where to go? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The Fortress language is designed to give the user something close to conventional maths notation ( not that any two maths papers use exactly the same notation ). The input exploits Unicode's symbols and follows conventions such as whitespace as the default multiplication operator.

The [Fortress site](http://projectfortress.sun.com/Projects/Community) has the reference implementation, it uses the Rats PEG implementation for its [grammar](http://projectfortress.sun.com/Projects/Community/browser/trunk/ProjectFortress/src/com/sun/fortress/parser) rather than EBNF.